# Using Big Query in Vite Project

Tags: javascript, google-bigquery, vite

I would like to use Googles Big Query client to query a Big Query DB from a Vite app. Following [the provided documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries#using_the_client_library) says to import BigQuery with the following statement:

```
const {BigQuery} = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');
```

Running this in App.tsx gives `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`

I tried switching to

```
import {BigQuery} from "@google-cloud/bigquery"
```

But then when I run the next line of code `const bigqueryClient = new BigQuery();` I get the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at loadProxy (gaxios.ts:65:9)
    at node_modules/gaxios/build/src/gaxios.js (gaxios.ts:75:1)
    at __require2 (chunk-OROXOI2D.js?v=60dbfa40:16:50)
    at node_modules/gaxios/build/src/index.js (index.ts:15:1)
    at __require2 (chunk-OROXOI2D.js?v=60dbfa40:16:50)
    at node_modules/gcp-metadata/build/src/index.js (index.ts:8:1)
    at __require2 (chunk-OROXOI2D.js?v=60dbfa40:16:50)
    at node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js (googleauth.js:19:21)
    at __require2 (chunk-OROXOI2D.js?v=60dbfa40:16:50)
    at node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/index.js (index.js:17:22)
```

How should I use the big query client in a vite app? Is it possible?

thank you!

Comment: Did you ran this command ```npm install --save @google-cloud/bigquery``` not sure how would you run this at vite app though.

Comment: I am facing the same issue here except with Speech to text API. Did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

define in vite.config.ts?

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import solidPlugin from "vite-plugin-solid";

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [solidPlugin()],
  server: {
    port: 3000,
  },
  build: {
    target: "esnext",
  },
  define: {
    global: {},
    process: {},
  },
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't that mess up using `process.env`? (I'm using Remix which has built-in `process.env` support)